# Cannot use Numpy module in Sublime Text because it's using the wrong python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext, python-3.10

Numpy is installed on my computer and I can import it when using the command line but does not work when using Sublime Text. The error I get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`.

I realize this is because the command line and Sublime Text are using two different versions of python.  When I run python in command line and check the system version, it is using Python 3.10.6 but the system version that Sublime Text is using is Python 3.9.9.  Both versions are in the /usr/bin/ directory.

So in command line, I execute
`ls /usr/bin/python* | grep python*`
to determine all the versions of python on my computer. Which results in

```
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10-config
/usr/bin/python3.9
/usr/bin/python3-config
```

So I created a 'New Build System' in Sublime Text to get it to use the latest Python version by using the following code

```
{
"path": "/usr/bin",
"cmd": ["python3.10", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

but receive this error when trying to execute a script:
`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3.10'`

If I revise the above cmd line to `"cmd": ["python3.9", "-u", "$file"],` and it will work and use that version of python. But numpy will not work with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Change your build system to this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3.10", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

And that's it. There is no `"path"` key for build systems. If you need to specify the path to a binary, just put it in the `"cmd"` array.

Comment: it is still giving me an error

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/python3.10'`

Comment: it's odd because when I just change python3.10 to python3.9 in the build system code, it works with no error.. but I can't use numpy with python3.9

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/python3.10` show? Is it red? Also, what does `which python3.10` show?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/python3.10` shows: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5921160 Nov 14 11:10 /usr/bin/python3.10`and it is not red.

and `which python3.10` shows: `/usr/bin/python3.10`

Comment: What command do you use to run Python 3.10 on the command line? If it's just `python` or `python3`, try putting that in your build system without `/usr/bin/` in front of it.

Comment: I use `python3`.  I tried ^this and it is still using python3.9 instead of python3.10